# Google Map - GeoRSS feed

Tags: xml, google-maps

I have a map in Google with marker points.  I used to use this URL in order which was a direct GeoRSS feed of XML data containing the marker coordinates and other data.  Now this URL takes me to a Google page with the markers on it.  Does anybody know where I can find the raw XML data?

http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&t=h&hl=en&msa=0&msid=100454954012875970674.00044e601b4c38e2f1766&vps=1&jsv=250a&output=georss

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "View in Google Earth" option to download the raw data in the standard KML format.

Answer (score 0):

Change output=georss to output=kml at the end of the URL.